# Mailer uploads images but KCFinder unable to display (WordPress)

Tags: civimail, images, kcfinder

I'm considerably confused about what's happening with Mailer & images (initially, I thought the problem was related to Mosaico, but it's now disabled): weirdly, I can upload an image to a newsletter draft -- and see it there, in the draft . . . but I cannot see it with KCFinder. I can't see anything at all in KCFinder, and it spits error messages back when I try to navigate to subfolders.

The image directory is: [civicrm.files]/persist/contribute/

Indeed, uploaded images (from either Mailer or Mosaico) land happily in this directory, but I can't view or use them from within CiviCRM.

Been reading related issues for days, and I can rule out imagick (specifically related to Mosaico) & permissions (settings are normal, at 755 for directories and 644 for the images themselves). Any insight would be most appreciated!

CiviCRM:5.19
WordPress: 5.2.4
PHP: 7.1[image]

Comment: Interestingly I've found similar that when I try to browse images when composing a email (not with mosaico) it opens kcfinder in a new window and freezes everything up, I lose all unsaved data. I'm on 5.18.4 though

Comment: Also tried changing the default editor to TinyMCE. No difference in behavior -- I can still upload without problem. In the CiviMail interface, I can see the uploaded images in the newsletter draft (and these also send without any problem). But I still can't browse them in KCFinder. (In Mosaico, I can't see them on the draft newsletter at all, but they do upload successfully from there).